# Android : If markers are overlapping each other on the map, then the click event is fired for the one at the back

Tags: android, google-maps

In our application, a lot of markers are drawn in different locations and in certain cases at a certain zoom level, markers overlap each other. So when I click on the marker, I expect the top marker's onMarkerClick to be fired but instead it is fired for the last hidden marker i-e the last marker, with no markers behind it.

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Can't you zoomin to maximum level?

Comment: I can. But that is not the solution to this issue at hand. I want to know is there a way that the marker on top takes up the click event, always, instead of the one at the back.